# Is it possible to access geoserver wfs layer from localhost:8080 in to web application?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, wfs

I want to add a WFS layer.

I am trying to get WFS layer from localhost:8080 geoserver. but I am getting  eoserver DateLineWrap in Openlayers.js file...

Comment: Please edit this question to ask a single question. Right now it is difficult to understand your question. Please see this post on tips to improve this question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question

Comment: WrapDateLine error is not caused by server, but due to projection system used. Check the projection system of your layers.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to add WMS form Geoserver to your Openlayers map.

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "layername",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/workspacename", {options} );
```

layername - name that will be display; 
workspacename - name of your workspace in geoserver; 
options - custom options like projection etc.;

In your options should be:

```
layers: 'workspacename:layername'
```

layername - name of layer in geoserver